# It's possibly change html element via PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, web, request

I have

```
<span id="first_name"></span>
```

From mysql i am getting "first_name" value and I want write this to #first_name.
JS do it great

```
$('span').text(firstNameFromDb);
```

But i can't do it on php. It's possibly? how i can do this?

Comment: <span> id="first_name"><?php echo $text; ?></span>

Comment: i have "index.html" with <span> and "some.php". how change <span> from "some.php"?

Comment: <span><?php include('some.php') ?></span>

Comment: @CapitanSlow you will have to change index.html to index.php and then put that. Another option is include your html file in your php file, like this:

<?php include('header.html'); echo $text; include('footer.html'); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly change the HTML from PHP, but you can do this by using an AJAX function through javascript. If you have included the jQuery js library into your project, create the following code in js:

```
$.ajax({
        url: getFirstName.php,
        data: {
            user: $first_name("#user-id").val(),
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#first_name").html(data);
        }

    });
```

Trigger the above jQuery function on a corresponding event.

in the getFirstName.php do the following logic:

```
$user_id = $_GET['user'];
$get_firstname = //mysql code to get the first name//;
echo $get_firstname;
```

This would do the trick.